# Sum of Column if multiple conditions are met

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I am struggling finding the correct formula to use

[image]

My intended target is the sum of Inventory (F) where:

1. Product # (A) matches desired # (in this case 1006910)
2. Seq (C) is less than first occurring in Dept 2 (J)

So, in this example I am looking for the result of 95

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use Sumifs, Can you explain Seq(C) < Dept 2

Comment: Your explanation needs a little more work, sorry, it's hard to understand :)

Comment: I am looking for the first occurrence of "2" in column "J" and need to use the corresponding value in C, so it would be "C" < 70

Comment: You mean C<70 (2 in J for the same Product 1006910

Comment: I would like to add column F for all values where A = 1006910 and C is less than 70 so 0+57+0+38

Comment: I am thinking it will require SUMIFS INDEX + MATCH

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
=SUM($F$2:$F$8*(--$C$2:$C$8<SUMPRODUCT(--($J$2:$J$8=2)*(--($A$2:$A$8=1006910))*$C$2:$C$8))*(--$A$2:$A$8=1006910))
```

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Change the references to correspond first and last row of your Data but keep $ for fixed references (the columns are as per your example)
You can write 1006910 in M2 for example and in N2 the formula:

```
=SUM($F$2:$F$255*(--$C$2:$C$255<SUMPRODUCT(--($J$2:$J$255=2)*(--($A$2:$A$255=M2))*$C$2:$C$255))*(--$A$2:$A$255=M2))
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
in that case you can write other products in M3, M4 and have the result by dragging down the above formula

**With Sumifs**
First find the corresponding C for Dept 2, in L2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$255*(--($A$2:$A$255=M2))*(--($J$2:$J$255=2)))
```

M2 is the product that you want
In N2:

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$255,$A$2:$A$255,M2,$C$2:$C$255,"<"&L2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help yass, after tinkering away at it all morning and a couple relaxing lunch bevs, I found a solution: (the end goal was to carry the data onto another worksheet)       '=SUMIFS('Inventory at each Op'!F:F,'Inventory at each Op'!A:A,Orders!A2,'Inventory at each Op'!C:C,"<"&MINIFS('Inventory at each Op'!C:C,'Inventory at each Op'!A:A,Orders!A2,'Inventory at each Op'!K:K,2))'